# codigo que imprima texto al final de un registro

Tags: php, mysql

tengo un reporte donde imprimio fechas de alzas de un bien a una persona
lo que quiero hacer es imprimir el siguienet texto"------ULTIMA LINA AL fechaAlza-----"
en el ultimo registro de las filas que tengan la misma fecha, actualmente lo imprimo asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo que necesito es que se muestre de esta manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el codigo donde lo hago, por el momento tengo 2 fechas quemadas para ver si me funciona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

```
aquí les dejo el codigo   

if($fecha_alza==="10/08/2021" || $fecha_alza==="02/08/2021")
                {?>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="7" align="center">------------------ 
                                          ----  U L T I M A    L I N E A  
                                                  <?php echo "   
                                                          AL".$fecha_alza ?>---</th></tr><?php
                }
                else{
                        echo "";
                    }
```

Comment: aqui lo que tendrias que hacer es cojer la primera fecha, y almacenarla en un temporal. Luego empiezas tu bucle, y vas comparando. Si la fecha de ese registro NO es igual a la temporal, entonces imprimes la linea y actualizas la variable temporal con esa fecha nueva.

Comment: Agrega el código de la imagen como texto.